# A sequence is norm convergent if and only if it converges weakly and uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear normed space; $x_n\in X\ (n\in\mathbb{N})$. Show that the
sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges on $X$ if, and only if, it converges weakly and 
uniformly on the ball $\{f\in X^*:||f||\le 1\}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forward direction is trivial.  For the converse, suppose $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x$, and use the Hahn-Banach theorem to obtain (for each $n$) an $f_n\in X^*$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ and $f_n(x_n-x)=\|x_n-x\|.$